# Database change are reflecting after deleting browser history

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer

I am using ASP.net C# IE 7, 8.

I have now implemented Ajax v 1.0 in my application. In the main window, there is a button to open a showdialogmodel. On opening this , I can make some modification in data entry form. Now close it. and again open this pop up. I am not able to see the changes made in database until the history is deleted.
Any suggestions?

Comment: that is probably not the fact. Please paste some code here, how do u post data and save it to db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cashing was required to remove. It solved the issue